# Turn anonymous function into a normal function

Tags: anonymous-function

```
    add_action( 'wp_footer', function () use($uniqueid, $height, $tileheight, $margin) {
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
            jQuery(function () {
                jQuery('." . $uniqueid . "').tilesGallery({
                    responsive: true,
                    anchorVertical: 'middle',
                    anchorHorizontal: 'center',
                    reloadOnResize: true,
                    captionHeight: '100%',
                    height: ".$height.",
                    tileMinHeight: ".$tileheight.",                     
                    margin: ".$margin.",
                });
            });
        </script>";
});
```

Hey there,

The problem is that I cannot use this function for php version less than 5.3. How can I turn it to something that will work in php version less than 5.3?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

> **Just use create_function($args, $code);**
> here how to use [create_function()](https://www.php.net/create_function)

```
$function = create_function('', 
'
global $uniqueid, $height, $tileheight, $margin;
    echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
            jQuery(function () {
                jQuery(\'.$uniqueid\').tilesGallery({
                    responsive: true,
                    anchorVertical: \'middle\',
                    anchorHorizontal: \'center\',
                    reloadOnResize: true,
                    captionHeight: \'100%\',
                    height: $height,
                    tileMinHeight: $tileheight,                     
                    margin: $margin,
                });
            });
        </script>";
'
);
```

Comment: I have added the missing bracket at the end but something else is wrong: "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting T_VARIABLE or '$' in /home/livetoth/public_html/wp-content/themes/royal-mag/functions/visual-composer.php(1202) : runtime-created function on line 1

Comment: Thank you for the spent time on my problem, but I do not see the difference between the two codes (the old one and the edited one, I have tried different combinations of single and double brackets but nothing seems to work? Can you checj again the edited version?

Comment: i edited it again , i just put it into a var '$function' and ajust the ' and ",  just use it directly

Comment: create_function, works like the basic code but put the code into
'' or ""